# What's a word for pliers and similar tools with a scissors action?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

Is there a word for all tools with a scissors action, e.g. scissors, pliers, side cutters, single hole punch, cable crimper, lopper, secateurs, post hole digger, etc.?

Specifically, any tool that requires its two arms which are connected on a common pivot to be moved relative to each other in order to complete the action of the tool.

This is required to enable a large number of diverse tools to be stored in such a way that they can easily be located, i.e. if I need the  BNC crimp tool or the scissors I would go to the labelled collection of 'double class-1–lever devices' and not the 'pointy tools with a single handle' collection. The idea being to find some obvious feature that that ties then together, not necessarily related to their function - a sort of mental hook. This would enable say 500 tools to be arranged and stored in, say, 10 categories on the bench.

Incidentally, loppers, secateurs and post hole diggers would fit the definition but wont be in my collection, unless I do the same for the garden shed.

Comment: @Lambie All of those tools pivot around a mid-point between the force and the effect.

Comment: If you must make a collection of a bunch of things, there are phrases that work: "scissor-like devices" or "scissor-action tools." If you can make that into one word, you win the clever prize, I guess.

Comment: Could you say why such a term would be needed?  I suppose you might want to have a term, if you were writing a thesis or study of them.  But why would one be needed?  Lack of need might be the reason why there is no established name.  If you look at the definitions of scissors, shears and secateurs, all of which operate on the same basic principle, as do some pliers, you find physical descriptions more or less similar, but no short classification name, such as 'intersecting bladed tools', inelegant as this is.  Why is it needed?

Comment: scissor-like tools, e.g. crucible tongs (Wikipedia)

Comment: @Lambie Perhaps you're thinking of different forms of those instruments. Cascabel's answer contains a nice illustration of a hole punch indicating the fulcrum around which the "arms" pivot, for example.

Comment: As Lambie is struggling to explain, we do have a term that differentiates scissor-type cutting from dykes and nippers. Scissors, secateurs and loppers and some wire cutters are *bypass cutters*. Note - few if any American gardeners or horticulturists will know what secateurs are. They are called pruners in the US. The best you could manage when rarely needing to specify the type of actuation on a specific tool is *plier-type action.

Comment: Pliers can cut or squeeze. There are also many tools that squeeze only (nutcrackers, tools for gripping a jar lid, hinged tongs...) And compasses have a hinge but are kept at a constant angle.

Comment: @Stuart ... in an ideal world.

Comment: @Lambie (and Phil Sweet): I was responding primarily to this comment: "hole punchers do not pivot" Those like the one in Cascabel's illustration certainly do pivot according to any common understanding of that word.

Comment: I guess *dikes* works too :(

Answer (score 2):

[Class-1 Lever (or 1st class lever)](https://www.explainthatstuff.com/toolsmachines.html)

> In a class-1 lever, the force you apply is on the opposite side of the fulcrum to the force you produce. A see-saw is an example of a class-1 lever. So is a pair of scissors:

-ExplainthatStuff.com/toolsmachines

Specifically, all of these types of scissor-action tools are sub-categorized as...

[***double class-1 lever***](https://www.school-for-champions.com/machines/levers_classess.htm) ***device.***

In other words, the fulcrum is in between the force and the effect, and the force of the 2 arms  is in the opposite direction of the effect. This includes all the tools you have listed.

[image]

And here is an image of a single-hole puncher. The action is obviously the same from a physics standpoint.

[image]

Crimpers (pliers), hedge-cutters, pruning shears, and even the hated [post-hole digger](https://www.homedepot.com/b/Outdoors-Garden-Center-Garden-Tools-Digging-Tools-Post-Hole-Diggers/N-5yc1vZc5ra) fall into this category.

All of the below tools whether they be crimpers, cutters, pliers, etc have 2 arms pivoting around a central point and have the same type of scissors action i.e. the direction of the effect is opposite to the force. **Notice that most of these crimping tools also offer a "cutting" edge for wire, essentially scissors for tougher materials.**

[image]

Comment: But a crowbar is also a class 1 lever device.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yup, because the fulcrum is in between the force and the effect...but it has only 1 arm. Nevertheless, all tools on the OP's list are class 1 levers

Comment: His words do not collocate.

Comment: Um, is "class 1 lever" a word? It's not even an understandable phrase unless you learn it in engineering class. It's jargon, only meaningful to a particular profession or discipline.

Comment: They are  'double class-1–lever devices', and that's obviously not remotely everyday English usage. Heartspring has added the 'terminology' tag, but I'd say that doesn't license terms so obviously in the physics domain.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  I edited to include your clarification...thanks

Comment: E A and 8356: This phrase is a good answer to the Q, although it's clearly not a Single Word, and probably not used in many households. Physicists, mechanics and engineers talk English every day, too. Well, some of them do, anyhow. +1.

Answer (score 1):

You could call all of these items ***hinged hand tools***. I wouldn't necessarily think of all of the listed examples upon hearing this term with no context, but I think it is an accurate descriptor of the list - every item is a hand tool which has a hinge.

That said, this term may not be sufficiently exclusive. There are other hand tools with a hinge that do not operate in the same scissors-type motion - a paper cutter, for example, is a hinged hand tool with a purpose basically like a scissor, but it only has a single moving part and is a class 3, rather than class 1 lever.

Comment: +1 ...and when they become **"unhinged"?** Sorry I could not resist the impulse.

Comment: I suppose a flail might be hinged.

Comment: It was a farm implement first.

Comment: I think he means a flail mower - works like a hammer mill.

Comment: A pair of compasses has a hinge, but is completely different.

Comment: @StuartF I'm not sure I'd call a compass a *hand tool*, a hand tool is powered by hand to accomplish some physical task, but a compass requires no meaningful power input whatsoever. I would call it an instrument rather than a hand tool - I also would not put other measuring/marking instruments like rulers, protractors, T-squares, or pencils in the it in the same "hand tool" category as pliers, hammers, handsaws, and shovels. Hand tools often stand in contrast to their powered counterparts, but there's no such thing as a power T-square.

Comment: [Courtesy of Alamy.](https://www.alamy.com/stock-photo/threshing-flail.html?sortBy=relevant)

Answer (score 1):

Speaking as a tool (and gadgets in general) junkie here:

Scissor type tools are different than plier type tools. Namely, the effective tool interface in a pair of scissors is where the two cutting edges, found on the "blades" (neither of which is usually very good at cutting by itself) *slide past* each other, fracturing the workpiece by controlled local shear forces, *stopping only when the entire working edges have passed each other.*

In general, when they are used to cut, these are "**scissor type**" or "**shear type**" tools, and are found in the "cutting tools" section of tool catalogues.

In the case of pliers, the effective tool faces (jaws) *meet* each other and *stop in the middle, unless they've trapped something in between them.*

These are usually called in general "**pliers**", and include tweezers and all other pincer style tools.

Both kinds of tools usually have a very similar hinge; the difference is in how the tool interfaces interact with the workpiece.

**A note about tool organization**:

In most catalogues, tools are categorized by *function* rather than by *structure*. That is, wood cutting tools, marking tools, metal cutting tools, plastic cutting tools (all of these cutting tools may belong to a meta-category "cutting tools"), pliers, abrasives and files, etc. An exception to this "rule" is the bifurcation between "electric tools" and "hand tools".

Comment: "Scissor type tools are different than plier type tools." Right, for example. Why is it so difficult to get English native speakers to see those tools do not collocate?